# Accessing results of pipe as variable?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, perl

I want to access the results of the last pipe command from current pipe command. For example:

```
echo "0x1a" | perl -le 'print hex("$RESULT_FROM_PIPE");'
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: "echo" output  goes directlry to perl ``stdin``, so you may access it with ``echo "0x1a" | perl -le 'print"Here is what I got on my STDIN:"; while (<>) {print;}'``

Comment: ... which is a verbose way to say `echo 0x1a | perl -ple '$_=hex'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking inspiration from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430877/bash-xargs-passing-variable

Even if it is a bit far-fetched, this works :

```
echo "0x1a" |  xargs sh -c 'perl -le "print hex(\"$1\");"' sh
26
```